# Como bloquear o acesso ao login depois de 3 tentativas erradas no firebase

Tags: android, firebase, login

Estava colocando o bloqueio depois de 3 tentativas erradas no login, porem encontrei em alguns fóruns que quando aguem mal intencionado tenta forçar varias senhas ele nao vai usar os campos de email e senha, esse bloqueio precisa ser feito pelas regras do firebase ate onde encontrei, mas nao consegui encontrar uma luz para criar as regras. Isso é mesmo verdade e tambem é possivel fazer esse bloqueio pelo firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode alterar as tentativas de login do firebase. O usuário bloqueado pode tentar novamente após alguns minutos, mas isso não é gerenciado por você.

O Firebase SDK limitará o usuário que tentar :

- várias tentativas incorretas de senha.
- várias criações de uma nova senha.
- várias tentativas de recuperação de senha.

Você pode ter mais infomações nesse link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits?hl=pt-br